# Aggregating a jQuery object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm authoring a plugin, and the plugin needs to do something like aggregate a set of jQuery objects. How does one do this?

For example:

```
<p><a>...</a></p>
<p><a>...</a></p>
```

With

```
(function( $ )
{
    $.fn.myfunc = function( settings )
    {

    };
})(jQuery);
```

Within the context of the plugin invoked with $('p').myfunc(), how would I return all the  elements, for example? The elements I'm returning will not necessarily be contained or near the elements selected, as this is just an example.

Comment: please clarify what do you mean by aggregate? do you want to include objects not part of the original selector as well? do you basically want this functionality - `$('p').add('a')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery also accepts an array, so you can build your own node stack and create a jQuery object out of it.

Example:

```
(function( $ )
{
    $.fn.myfunc = function( settings )
    {
        var stack = [];
        stack.concat(this.find('a').toArray());
        stack.concat($('a.hot-links').toArray());
        return $($.unique(stack));
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Or simply:

```
return this.find('a'); // as return result of plugin
```

Also, look at [.pushStack()](http://api.jquery.com/pushStack/), which lets you add elements to an already existing jQuery object.

Comment: A slight point of clarification, `.pushStack()` doesn't add any elements to the jQuery object, it returns a *new* jQuery object with the combination of the elements, the old/original object still has the same elements.

Comment: @nick, good catch, basically you might as well work with arrays and create a new jQuery object out of it when you're done. Though not needed when doing minute concatenations.