# Strange behaviour of jQuery add() method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two of the same(?) pieces of code:

```
var x = document.createElement('div');
var y = document.createElement('div');
var z = $().add(x).add(y);
console.log(z);
```

and

```
var x = document.createElement('div');
var y = document.createElement('div');
var z = $();
z.add(x);
z.add(y);
console.log(z);
```

First example show me: +Object[div, div]

And other: Object[ ]

Why???

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d3x7gsLu/

More magic: http://jsfiddle.net/d3x7gsLu/1/

UPD:

First correct answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31798686/3558278

Now my question:

And how make it (append elements into internal collection) without creation new jQuery object?
Because in real I have many and many elements.

UPD2:

Answer here: [Aggregating a jQuery object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619353/aggregating-a-jquery-object/3619552#3619552)

Thanks for All!

Comment: Because jQuery is antichrist.

Comment: So you are asking how to add elements to an existing jQuery object, changing that existing object rather than creating a second one?

Comment: @nnnnnn now -- yes ))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [jQuery API](https://api.jquery.com/add/):

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the
>   .add() method **constructs a new jQuery object** from the union of those
>   elements and the ones passed into the method. The argument to .add()
>   can be pretty much anything that $() accepts, including a jQuery
>   selector expression, references to DOM elements, or an HTML snippet.

This means that your examples aren't equal, to be equal your second example should look like this:

```
var x = document.createElement('div');
var y = document.createElement('div');
var z = $();
z = z.add(x);
z = z.add(y);
console.log(z);
```

Comment: Ok. And how make it (append elements into internal collection) without creation new jQuery object?

Answer (score 0):

`$.add()` returns a new value, it doesn't modify the original value of `z`. In the first example you're saying:

> Create an empty jQuery object, add the element in variable `x` to it
>   then add the element in variable `y` to it. Assign this object to the
>   variable `z`.

After all this the value of `z` will be an object containing two elements.

In the second example you're saying:

> Create an empty jQuery object. Assign this object to the variable `z`. Then see what would happen if you added the element in variable `x` to this object. Then see what would happen if you added the element in variable `y` to this object.

After all this the value of `z` is still the original empty object.

To make example 2 behave like example 1 you would need to update the code like this:

```
var x = document.createElement('div');
var y = document.createElement('div');
var z = $();
z=z.add(x);
z=z.add(y);
console.log(z);
```

As you can see the value of `z` is being updated.